# Command line to remove all BigQuery datasets with a given prefix

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to delete all datasets with a given prefix using a command on the command-line. I've tried this:

```sh
PREFIX=myprefix && PROJECT="myproject" && \
  gcloud alpha bq datasets list --project ${PROJECT} --filter="ID~${PREFIX}" --format="value(ID)" | \
  cut -d ':' -f 2 | \
  xargs gcloud alpha bq datasets delete --project $PROJECT --remove-tables --quiet
```

but it fails with

> ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.bq.datasets.delete) unrecognized arguments:
> myprefix_dataset1
> myprefix_dataset2
> myprefix_dataset3

I think the problem is in my xargs command so I admit that this isn't strictly speaking a BigQuery question, but I'm hoping someone can help me with my shoddy linux scripting skills anyway or tell me a better way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found the answer for this, I was in need of similar cmd and came across this.
I modified you cmd a little for `xargs` to use option `-L1` and that worked for me. Something like

```
PREFIX=myprefix && PROJECT=myproject && gcloud alpha bq datasets list \
--project ${PROJECT} --filter="ID~${PREFIX}" --format="value(ID)" | \
 cut -d ':' -f 2 | xargs -L1 gcloud alpha bq datasets delete \
--project $PROJECT --remove-tables --quiet
```